# File I/0 Function what type of arguments does it take?

Tags: c++, file-io

Hey i'm writing a game in C++ and i don't understand what type of arguments the save function takes. I assumed you would use the file name for the arguments but i just get an error.

> 4    IntelliSense: a reference of type "std::ofstream &" (not const-qualified) cannot be > initialized with a value of type "const
>   char [9]" c:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\C++
>   Programming\Marooned\Marooned\MainApp.cpp 13  13  Marooned

```
void MenuText::print()
{
cout<< "Story= " << mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
}
void MenuText::save(ofstream& outFile)
{
outFile<< "Story = " << mText<< endl;
outFile<< endl;
}
void MenuText::load(ifstream& inFile)
{
string garbage;
inFile>> garbage >> mText;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what type of arguments does it take?

Comment: When dealing with a library, consulting the documentation of the function you are using is the first step.

Comment: can you add your code here? most probably you are passing file name where ofstream reference is expected. You can try passing _std::ofstream("yourfilename")_.

Comment: I forgot to add the function code its added now.

Comment: can you show MainApp.cpp line 13?

Comment: @bobah  your suggestion worked.  Do you want to write an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are calling the `save` function with a literal string (the filename I guess by the error message). You should call it with an existing `ofstream` instead.

Something like

```
MenuText menuText;

std::ofstream output("some file name");

menuText.save(output);
```

Comment: Which leaves open the question of _why_ `save` takes an `ofstream`, and not just any `ostream`.  Looks like a case of poor design to me.

Answer (score 0):

std::ofstream& is a reference to an output stream. So you need to pass in an ofstream (Output File stream): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/